# sort datatable by a field

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

```
  var course = from b in DbModle.courses
                            where b.name == "test"
                            select b;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
    foreach (var course1 in course_university)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = course1.name;
        dr[1] = course1.id;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

How can I sort `DataTable` by id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataTables cannot be sorted directly, but you can create a DataView of the table with a specific sort order.

```
var view = new DataView(dt) { Sort = "id" };
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using this:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "id";
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

foreach (var row in dv) {  
   //. . .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not sort in your original query?

```
var courses = from c in DbModel.courses
              where c.Name == "test"
              orderby c.ID
              select c;

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));

foreach (var course in courses)
{
    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = course1.name;
    dr[1] = course1.id;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: how can do this?write a example

Comment: Check out the orderby line in the LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `DataTableExtensions` and `DataRowExtensions`:

```
var view = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(c=>c.Field<int>("id")).AsDataView();
```